# Play sound from NSData using AVAudioPlayer iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I would like to play a sound file retrieved from my server, as a base 64 encoded file.

So far, I have decoded the file using base64 and written it to a file as so:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];            
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);             
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"voicemail.wav"]];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:filepath contents:[responseDict objectForKey:@"ResponseData"] attributes:nil];
```

However, I am having trouble actually playing the sound file. My code returns the error:

> The operation couldn't be completed. OSStatus error 2003334207.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
AVAudioPlayer *sound = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err] autorelease];
if (! sound) {
    NSLog(@"Sound had error %@", [err localizedDescription]);
} else {
    [sound prepareToPlay]; 
    [sound play];
}
```

Comment: I would run this in the simulator and take a look at voicemail.wav and more sure it really is a proper wav file, using `file voicemail.wav` and play it in iTunes etc. Also make sure you assign the `AVAudioPlayer` instance to a strong/retain property as with your currently example code it will probably be (auto)released even before it starts to play sound.

Comment: Thanks Mattias, the problem was in wav file and able to resolve it. Thanks for showing the way.

Comment: Nice. Any error related to usage of the iOS API or thing other people could encounter? then I think you should answer your own questions with the findings and how you solved it.

Comment: @Shreya me have the same problem..? can you provide me the solution for that....i am very thankful to you.....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Himanshu

As suggested by the Mattias Wadman, I tried to play downloaded file using vlc/iTunes media player and the file were not playing. 
So the problem may be in the encoding or in decoding of file, not in the play audio code. I checked for the same and there were some extra characters embedded while encoding. 
We worked on encoding and resolved the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What exactly you did while working with encoding to resolved this issue, will you please elaborate i am facing the same issue while playing the audio file retrieved from server as a NSData.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSData *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FileName.mp3"]
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];   
    AVAudioPlayer *sound = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err] autorelease];
      if (! sound) {
        NSLog(@"Sound had error %@", [err localizedDescription]);
        } else {
       [sound prepareToPlay]; 
       [sound play];
         }
```